# Рабочая область слишком большая Google Tag Manager

Tags: json, google-tag-manager

Всем привет.
Совсем недавно начал использовать Google Tag Mager, чтобы добавить на сайт структурированные данные (разметка JSON-LD). Но на днях столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При добавлении очередных тегов и триггеров появилась ошибка: "Рабочая область слишком большая".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было добавлено только 2\3 нужных тегов и триггеров, ума не приложу как добавить разметку на оставшиеся страницы. Возможно, как-то можно уменьшить размер добавленных тегов, чтобы добавить еще ? На данный момент в "контейнере" 41 тег и 11 триггеров.
Сайт на туристическую тематику и разметка добавлялась на страницу каждого тура, а именно "Event" и "Product".
Пример: https://www.apex-mountain.ru/voshozhdenie-na-monblan/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как некоторые туры проводятся 4 раза в год (актуальный пример выше), то для каждой даты добавляется своя разметка "Event", где отличаются только "starDate" и "endDate". Возможно есть какой-то способ уместить 4 разных даты в один "Event" и таким путем уменьшить количество "Event" для каждого мероприятия ?
Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас в контейнере появляется два и более тегов, которые решают одну и ту же задачу, то всегда стоит попробовать объединить эти теги в один, а задачу решить с помощью переменных и триггеров.

В вашем случае пути решения два и оба они подразумевают, что у вас в контейнере останется один тег, отвечающий за Event, и один тег, отвечающий за Product.

Оба эти тега будут представлять шаблоны, в которые будут подставляться значения переменных. И вот здесь возникают два пути.

Первый - более оптимальный с точки зрения полноты данных и устойчивости к ошибкам. Вам нужно у разработчиков попросить передавать в dataLayer по коду страницы над кодом контейнера GTM все данные о описаннлм на данной странице туре, которые нужны для разметки.

Например, это будет название, описание, даты начала и окончания и другие необходимые поля. Как это реализовать с технической точки зрения описано тут:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Далее в своих тегах вы просто с помощью переменных с типом "Переменная уровня данных" забираете эти значения и используете их при построении объекта JSON-LD в разметке.

Второй путь - получать эту информацию со страницы с помощью парсинга ее содежримого через GTM. Здесь вам понадобится знание CSS и уверенность в том, что структура кода страниц не будет меняться.

Все отличие от первого пути, что вместо переменных с типом "Переменная уровня данных" вы используете переменные с типом "Собственный код JavaScript". С помощью этих переменных и CSS-селекторов вы сможете получать со страницы нужные вам данные.

Первый путь предпочтительнее. Если у вас структура кода страниц изменится, то во втором случае вам придется все перенастраивать. Также во втором случае вам нужны знания JavaScript и CSS, а в первом достаточно просто составить техническое задание для разработчиков и уметь создавать переменные в интерфейсе GTM.

В результате в контейнере у вас останутся два тега, несколько переменных и несколько триггеров. По сравнению с тем множеством сущностей, которое есть у вас   сейчас, вы получите выигрыш в разы и по размеру контейнера и по удобству его использования.